# Probability of Selecting Jars

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 20 jars, and 15 jars have 2 balls each while 5 jars have 1 ball each. If, from the 35 balls, I select 30 at random, what's the probability that I have sampled x (15, 16, etc.) number of jars (each jar being the same except that 15 held 2 balls)?

I've tried a combinatorics approach, but I've put myself at a dead end.

Comment: Not sure this is clear....how are you drawing a ball?  Are you A. picking a jar at (uniform) random and then choosing a ball from it, also uniformly randomly?  or B. are you choosing amongst the $35$ balls uniformly at random (so each ball has an equal chance of being drawn). ?

Comment: Sorry, picking from 35 balls uniformly.

Comment: You should edit the problem to reflect that.  And, just to be clear, in the end you are only asking about the raw number of sampled jars, not their type, yes?

Comment: If you pick thirty balls, and you happened to get exactly 15 jars, is it possible that you picked any of the balls from the jars which had exactly one ball in it to begin with?  So then, which balls are possible for you to take if you end with exactly fifteen jars used?  What is the probability of this occuring?

Comment: In general you may need the multi-hypergeometric pmf, with some counting as well. In this question, there is only $5$ balls not picked, so the situation is much simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps organize our thoughts if we temporarily assume that every ball is labeled differently.  Say, for example, with its urn number, and it whether it is ball1 or ball2 (in the case of multiple balls in same urn).

For exactly 15 jars to have been used:

> the jars must have been specifically the ones with two balls in them each.

This occurs with probability:

> $1/\binom{35}{30}\approx 3\cdot 10^{-6}$

For exactly 16 jars to have been used, one of two things will be true:

> You picked two balls each from each of 14 of the jars with two balls available, one from the remaining jar with two balls available, and one from a jar with only one available,  **OR** two balls each from each of 14 jars with two balls available and one from each of two jars with one available.

We count how many ways we can accomplish this:

> In the first case, choose which of the jars with two balls had only one of the balls used.  Then, which of the balls.  Finally, choose which of the jars with only one ball was used.  There are then $15\cdot 2\cdot 5=150$ possibilities for this case.  The second case, pick which jar with two balls we didn't take any of, and then pick which of the jars with only one available were used.  There are then $15\cdot\binom{5}{2}=150$ possibilities.  The probability of occurrence is then $300/\binom{35}{30}$.

Equivalently worded, we may think of where the locations of the **unused** balls are kept.  Doing so will arrive at the same conclusions as above.  You may continue similarly for the remaining cases.

---

For 18 jars to have been used, keeping track of cases becomes messier than before, so I will introduce additional notation.  Consider the triple $(A,a,b)$.  Let $A$ be the number of jars which have two available that had both used.  Let $a$ be the number of jars which have two available that had only one used.  Let $b$ be the number of jars used which had only one available.

For example, in the case of $15$ jars used, we had $(15,0,0)$.  In the case of $16$ jars used, we had $(14,1,1)$ or $(14,0,2)$.  Note that the total number of balls taken will be $2A+a+b$.  The total number of jars used will be $A+a+b$.  Also, $A+a$ cannot exceed 15, and $b$ cannot exceed five.

Note also that to have $k$ jars used, $A$ must be $30-k$.  This is because we want $A+a+b=k$ and $2A+a+b=30$.  Subtracting the first equation from the second yields the result.

---

For $18$ jars we have the following possibilities:

$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
(12,1,5)\\
\hline (12,2,4)\\
\hline (12,3,3)\\
\hline\end{array}$

$(12,0,6)$ is not possible since there are not six available jars with only one available.  Similarly, $(12,4,2)$ is not possible since there are not enough jars with two available for that to happen.

Counting each case:  Pick the jars used for $A$.  Pick the jars used for $a$.  Pick which of the balls was used for each jar in $a$.  Pick the jars used for $b$.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
(12,1,5)&\binom{15}{12}\binom{3}{1}\cdot 2\cdot \binom{5}{5}\\
\hline (12,2,4)&\binom{15}{12}\binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^2\cdot \binom{5}{4}\\
\hline (12,3,3)&\binom{15}{12}\binom{3}{3}\cdot 2^3\cdot \binom{5}{3}\\
\hline\end{array}$

Summing over all cases gives $66430$ possible outcomes.  Dividing by the sample space size, $\binom{35}{30}$ yields the probability $\frac{4745}{23188}\approx 0.2046$

Comment: Why is it $15\cdot\binom{5}{2}$ for the second case when we only take 14 jars of two balls, and $\binom{5}{2}$ represents the one-ball jar combinations?

Comment: @sebastian because there are 15 ways to choose which fourteen of the jars we used. Equivalently, 15 ways to choose the jar we didn't use

Comment: Ah, ok. So when I want, say, two jars empty, then it's simply 15 choose 2, since that 15 is reduced form of 15 choose 1?

Comment: I'm working out the rest, but if you could explain it for the case of 18 jars, that would help clarify my confusion as well, because 18 jars has the case that 1 of the 15 has one ball, and 2 of the 15 have zero, leading to all five of the one-ball jars being used.

Comment: @sebastianross The case of 18 jars and some more convenient notation and observations added at the end.